# Teradata - While loop in Stored Procedure doesn't work

Tags: stored-procedures, while-loop, teradata

I wrote the below script using the while loop in a stored procedure against a dynamic SQL and is not producing the desired results.  The codes in Order Table are horizontal vs lookup reference code table displays vertical Rsn’s codes.  Is there any workaround? The code has no errors; however, one of the results is returned (3333 150).

Desired result:

```
OrderID MAIN_ID
1111    3
1111    104
2222    67
2222    162
3333    150
3333    67
4444    67
4444    48
4444    7
```

Code:

```
create PROCEDURE mydb.sp_test() SQL SECURITY CREATOR 
BEGIN
    DECLARE in_CurrRsnSK int;
    DECLARE in_CurrErrDefID int;
    DECLARE in_MaxSK int;
    DECLARE in_Rsn1 smallint;
    DECLARE in_Rsn2 smallint;
    DECLARE in_Rsn3 smallint;
    DECLARE in_CurrRsn smallint;
    DECLARE in_NumMatches smallint;
    DECLARE in_Type varchar(50);
    DECLARE in_Code varchar(3);
    DECLARE in_CurrIteration smallint ;

    SET in_CurrRsnSK=1;
    SET in_CurrErrDefID=1;
    SET in_CurrIteration=1;
---------------------------------------------------------
drop table temp_order;
drop table temp_code;
drop table temp_Match;
drop table temp_Final;
---------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE temp_order 
     (OrderID int  ,SubID int   ,Code varchar(2)
       ,Rsn smallint            ,RsnMatchFlag varchar(1)  
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;      
---------------------
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (1111,1,'A7',116);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (1111,2,'A8',496);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (1111,3,'A8',562);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,1,'A3',247);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,108,'A8',455);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,109,'A8',255);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,110,'A8',507);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,111,'A8',455);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,112,'A8',255);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (2222,113,'A8',507);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (3333,1,'A3',247);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (3333,2,'A8',228);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (3333,3,'A8',455);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (3333,4,'A8',507);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (4444,1,'A3',247);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (4444,2,'A6',145);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (4444,3,'A8',189);
insert into temp_order  (OrderID,SubID,Code,Rsn)      values (4444,4,'A8',249);

update  temp_order set RsnMatchFlag=Null;
--------------------------
 CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE  temp_code
  (   SK int,  Main_id int,  Code varchar(2), Rsn1 smallint,Rsn2 smallint,Rsn3 smallint  
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;      

insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)  values (1,150,'A8',228,455,507);
insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)   values (2,162,'A8',255,455,507);
insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)   values (3,48,'A8',189,249,'');
insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)   values (4,104,'A8',496,562,'');
insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)   values (5,3,'A7',116,'','');
insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)   values (6,7,'A6',145,'','');
insert into temp_code   (SK,Main_id,Code,Rsn1,Rsn2,Rsn3)   values (7,67,'A3',247,'','');
-- Check OrderID for each reason
    /***************************************************************/
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE   temp_Match 
       ( OrderID int   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;   
-------------------Final table with Order ID & Code Main id
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE  temp_Final
    (   OrderID int    ,Main_id int  ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;   

select MAX(sk)    into in_MaxSK    from temp_Code;
--loop starts
    WHILE in_CurrRsnSK<= in_MaxSK
    DO
    BEGIN
        -- Get Rsn
     select (case when Rsn1=0 then -1 else Rsn1 end)   into :in_Rsn1 from  temp_Code  where SK=in_CurrRsnSK ;
     select (case when Rsn2=0 then -1 else Rsn2 end)   into :in_Rsn2 from  temp_Code  where SK=in_CurrRsnSK ;
     select (case when Rsn3=0 then -1 else Rsn3 end)   into :in_Rsn3 from  temp_Code  where SK=in_CurrRsnSK ;    
     select Code  into :in_Code  from temp_Code  where SK=in_CurrRsnSK ;  
     select Main_ID  into :in_CurrErrDefID  from temp_Code  where SK=in_CurrRsnSK ;  

        SET in_NumMatches=((CASE WHEN in_Rsn1>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  +
                                                (CASE WHEN in_Rsn2>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  +
                                                (CASE WHEN in_Rsn3>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END));
        -- Find Matching Status
        SET in_CurrRsn=in_Rsn1;

        WHILE in_CurrIteration<= 3 AND in_CurrRsn>0  DO
         BEGIN
            UPDATE TOr
                FROM temp_order TOr
                    ,( SELECT S1.OrderID,  MIN(S1.Subid) AS SeqNo
                                FROM temp_order As S1
                                          WHERE S1.Code=in_Code
                                          AND S1.Rsn=in_CurrRsn
                                           AND S1.RsnMatchFlag is null
                              GROUP BY S1.OrderID             ) SQ
                 SET RsnMatchFlag='Y'
                 WHERE SQ.OrderID=TOr.OrderID
                        and SQ.SeqNo=TOr.Subid;
            -- next reason
            SET in_CurrIteration=in_CurrIteration  + 1;
            SET in_CurrRsn=(CASE WHEN in_CurrIteration=2 THEN in_Rsn2
                                 WHEN in_CurrIteration=3 THEN in_Rsn3
                                 ELSE -1 END);
        END;
        END WHILE;
        -- Find Matching Claims
        DELETE FROM  temp_Match;

        INSERT INTO  temp_Match (OrderID)
          SELECT OrderID
                FROM  temp_order
                WHERE RsnMatchFlag='Y'
                GROUP BY OrderID
                HAVING COUNT(*)=in_NumMatches;

       IF ACTIVITY_COUNT>0 THEN      ---any matches/
       BEGIN
            -- Insert into the Final Table - Order / Main_id List
            INSERT INTO temp_Final (OrderID, Main_id)
              SELECT MATCH.OrderID   ,in_CurrErrDefID
                    FROM temp_Match   MATCH
                        LEFT JOIN temp_Final FN
                          ON FN.OrderID=MATCH.OrderID
                          aND FN.Main_id=in_CurrErrDefID
                    WHERE (FN.OrderID IS NULL or FN.OrderID = ' ');
            -- Remove Code records that were used
            DELETE FROM temp_order
                WHERE temp_order.OrderID in (SELECT OrderID FROM temp_MATCH)
                         and temp_order.RsnMatchFlag='Y';
        END;  -- matches
        END IF;
        -- Clear any partial matches
        UPDATE temp_order
           SET RsnMatchFlag=NULL
           WHERE RsnMatchFlag='Y';
        -- Next reason
        SET in_CurrRsnSK=in_CurrRsnSK + 1;
    END;
   END WHILE;
END ;

CALL mydb.sp_test();
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.  Desired result formatted. thanks.

Comment: You could probably do this with more SQL and less looping. But I don't see anywhere that you reset `in_CurrIteration` for the inner loop.

Comment: As Fred said, move `SET in_CurrIteration=1;` after the begin of the 1st LOOP. And the 6 Selects to *Get Rsn* should be combined into a single Select.

Comment: Fred / dnoeth - thanks a lot on your recommendation. Moving and adding sql security creator & declare handler gave me the correct results.  It matched and read all the order id, however when the Rsn in order table is not in sequential order matching to Code Table Rsn1, Rsn2, Rsn3, it does not read.  Eg – Order  (2222,111,'A8',455); /(2222,112,'A8',255); /(2222,113,'A8',507)  rows are unassigned. Can you suggest on how to accomplish and add to logic?

Comment: Fred, Kindly share some sample logic on more sql and less looping.  Thanks.